# PHP Submit form highlighting textfield on error with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, forms

My website consists of a few files. First, I've got index.html, where my form details are located in. It contains JQuery, so when the user presses submit, the site sends the filled in information to a .php-file which processes all the information (check the information, and upload it to MySQL database if the information is correct). The .html-file is formatted with the help of a .css-file.

All of this works correctly. There are no errors in the JQuery, HTML page or PHP-file.

Next, I'd like to add a functionality which can do either of the following two things:

- The form has three required textfields. When the user fails to fill in either one of them, or fail to pass the email-check located in the .php-file, I'd like to see the textfields where the error occurs highlighted in red (e.g. the background colour of the textfield should become red).
- When successfull, the form should get hidden while an other form (located on the same location but hidden through the .css-file) becomes visible. This contains just one label, and has the text: "Submission is succesfull."

I'm not too experienced with JQuery so I was kind of glad to see the JQuery calling the .php-file works already. Even so, I'm clueless on how I should start on the above described problem. Can anyone provide me with a simple example or explanation on how to continue?

Index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/assets/styles.css" type="text/css"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#contactForm").validate({
            debug: false,
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('resources/assets/sharedatabase.php', $("#contactForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                 // $('#contactForm').hide();
                  $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>

<div class="form">
<div class="formcontainer">
<form action="" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
<fieldset>
And so on...


<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
...
    }
    */
}
```

Next, the PHP-file:

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && ... $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if (!empty($empty_name)) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'msg'   => "Name"
            ));
            exit;
            }
        elseif (!empty($empty_company))  {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'msg'   => "Company"
            ));
            exit;
            }
        elseif (!empty($empty_email))     {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'msg'   => "Email"
            ));
            exit;
            }
        else    
             {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'msg'   => "Something else went wrong."
            ));
            exit;
            }
    }
}
//send
else
{
    mysql_connect("site.nl", "username", "********") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("databasename") or die(mysql_error());

    //creating values here

    $query="xxxxx";
    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
    mysql_close();

    echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => false,
            ));
            exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form via AJAX, or submitting to the PHP file?

Comment: I'm using JQuery to post the form data to the PHP file.

Comment: You could use the `.done()` and `.fail()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-3

Comment: @Bondye I'm gonna try that one when I'm getting home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you submit the data, check it for the required fields. The best way to show form errors is to simply add an 'error' class to the form items.

With CSS, format your error class to be whatever (red background on the form field or something). In jQuery you could do something like:

```
// Check form fields for error.
if($('#name').val == ""){
  // Apply an error class.
  $('#name').addClass("error");
}

// On a successful submission, hide the old form and show the new one.
$('#oldForm').hide();
$('#newForm').show();
```

Without seeing your submission code I can't help you more, but you can do back-end validation and pass the result to the front-end using AJAX. This would allow you to verify that the form submission has made it into the database before you show the new form.

Comment: I came to this far, but the I got stuck. How can I, after verifying in the PHP-file, pass back to the HTML-site if the submission is succesfull, or, in case it's not, what textfield are faulty?

Comment: Show me da codez plz. I need to see your JavaScript (how you submit the form), and part of your PHP.

Comment: Cool, so in your JSON response, return the name of the field that is causing the error. Then in your jQuery, check if 'error' is true, and then add the error class to the 'field'.